# Count spaces (ASCII code 32) at the beginning and end of string

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

I'm struggling with the following problem. I have a column with this kind of data:

```
'abbb ccc   '
'    aaa abbb ccc'
'abbb ccc   '
'   aaa abbb ccc   '
'   ccc'
'aaa abbb'
```

I want to count the number of spaces on the left and the number of spaces on the right of each string.

Comment: Get total length - trimmed length of same string

Answer (score 6):

Try using a combination of `LEN`, `LTRIM`, and `REVERSE`:

```
SELECT
    LEN(col) - LEN(LTRIM(col)) AS num_left,
    LEN(REVERSE(col)) - LEN(LTRIM(REVERSE(col))) AS num_right
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

As @AaronDietz mentioned in the comment below, `LEN` actually also trims whitespace on the right.  But `LEN` does not affect leading whitespace.  To compensate for this we can reverse the string and then do the calculation using `LTRIM`.

Comment: Why not just use datalength instead? Much simpler than using reverse like that. :) datalength(col) - len(col) as RightCount

Comment: Hello Tim, Many Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(50)='abbb ccc   '
DECLARE @t NVARCHAR(50)='    aaa abbb ccc'
SELECT
    RightSpaces = LEN(RTRIM(REVERSE(@s))) - LEN(@s),
    LeftSpaces = LEN(@t) - LEN(LTRIM(REVERSE(@t)))
```

output

```
RightSpaces LeftSpaces
3           4
```

or you can use DATALENGTH and remove the need for REVERSE

```
SELECT
    LeftSpaces  = (DATALENGTH(@s)- DATALENGTH(RTRIM(@s)))/2,
    RightSpaces = (DATALENGTH(@t)- DATALENGTH(LTRIM(@t)))/2
```

output

```
RightSpaces LeftSpaces
3           4
```

Comment: Hello Mazhar, Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can ditch `LEN` and `TRIM` functions and use [`PATINDEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) instead:

```
SELECT
    str,
    PATINDEX('%[^ ]%', str) - 1 AS leading_spaces,
    PATINDEX('%[^ ]%', REVERSE(str)) - 1 AS trailing_spaces
FROM testdata
```

Output:

```
| str                | leading_spaces | trailing_spaces |
+--------------------+----------------+-----------------+
| abbb·ccc···        | 0              | 3               |
| ····aaa·abbb·ccc   | 4              | 0               |
| abbb·ccc···        | 0              | 3               |
| ···aaa·abbb·ccc··· | 3              | 3               |
| ···ccc             | 3              | 0               |
| aaa·abbb           | 0              | 0               |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5a51a3/10)

Answer (score 1):

Use datalength to get the full length
len will rtrim

```
declare @t varchar(100) = '   abbb ccc     ';

select len(@t) as 'len', datalength(@t) as 'datalength',
       datalength(@t) - datalength(ltrim(@t)) as 'left',
       datalength(@t) - datalength(rtrim(@t)) as 'right'
```

Comment: Using `datalength` is what Sean Lange recommended in a comment to another answer. However, does a blank have the same number of bytes in every character set? Maybe this should rather be `(datalength(@lt) - datalength(ltrim(@lt))) / datalength(' ')` to make sure to count each blank only once.

Comment: Hello Thorsten, thanks :) and yes the number of bytes is the same in every charset

Comment: @ThorstenKettner is there any language you know of where a single space takes more than 1 character? I have never encountered that or ever heard of it.

Comment: I believe the OP's data type is CHAR(32) and not varchar (from the title), he doesn't specify tho.

Comment: @EzLo You took char(32) as a data type?

Comment: For the right side I would use len instead of datalength - rtrim. Seems a little odd to me when a single function does the same thing. :)

Comment: @SeanLange You are free to use what you chose.

Comment: @Sean Lange: Yes, utf-32. Try `select datalength(N' ')`. I'm getting two bytes for the blank when I run this.

Comment: I just found it kind of funny because in your answer you stated that len will rtrim but then you didn't use it.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner dur....my brain was not engaged before the keyboard. You could simply divide by 2 if utf-32.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner select datalength(' '); returns 1

Comment: @paparazzo: Yes. And `select datalength(N' ')` returns 2. So depending on the character set the blank takes another number of bytes. Knowing this, we'll "simply" have to check which character set is being used for the column, get the number of bytes used for a blank in that character set and divide the datalength difference by that number. Quick and easy ;-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Point is / datalength(' ') does not solve the problem.  If you you know it is nvarchar then just / 2.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that dividing by `datalength(' ')` doesn't work. This is why I said you need to find out the column's character set. You should do this in the query itself, though, by selecting the information from the system tables, to make this query safe for data model changes. Or to make it short: just don't use `datalength` when you want to count characters rather than bytes.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this...

```
SELECT Len(col + 'End') - Len(Rtrim(col)) - 3 AS Rno, 
       Len(col) - Len(Ltrim(col))             AS Lno
```

Since LEN function does not include trailing spaces, you could add extra text at the end of the string and remove the length of that text later.
Refer this example (4 white spaces)

`SELECT LEN('test    ')` = 4
`SELECT LEN('test    ' + 'End')` = 11
`SELECT LEN('test    ' + 'End') - 3` = 8

Comment: That is an odd way of dealing with this. It works I guess but weird.

Comment: @SeanLange, This way trailing spaces will not be removed. :)

Comment: I understand that but is a very odd way to handle it. You could use datalength which counts all the spaces.

Comment: @SeanLange, datalength will not solve the problem.   Refer this example: http://rextester.com/SXEV41589  

`Declare @x NVARCHAR(10) = 'test'; 
DECLARE @y CHAR(10)='test';   

SELECT DATALENGTH('Test');
SELECT DATALENGTH(N'Test');
SELECT DATALENGTH(@x);
SELECT DATALENGTH(@y);`  Results: 4, 8, 8, 10.

Comment: Yeah but it isn't like a single column is going to change datatypes. You just have to handle the datatype of the column at hand.